# Uploading files to SharePoint containing the ampersand character

Tags: sharepoint-designer, wss-3.0

I'm trying to upload files and folders to a library using SharePoint Designer 2007 (on a WSS 3.0 SharePoint site).

It's giving me an error when I try to upload empty folders or folders that have an **&** in their name.

OS: Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008.

Can someone please assist?

Comment: I realize this was asked 4 years ago, but it just so happened to bump to the top of the list today... and I just had a user ask me about it not ten minutes ago. Intentional or not, the timing was awesome.

Answer (score 8):

There are certain characters that SharePoint does not allow in the filename. Unfortunately the ampersand character is one of them! Here is a list I've found, I'm not sure if there's an official list somewhere:

```
char[] InvalidFilenameCharacters = new[] { '\\', '/', ':', '*', '?', '"', '<', '>', '|', '#', '{', '}', '%', '~', '&' };
```

Comment: In addition to the characters Alex Angas listed, SharePoint also doesn't support files and folders with Unicode 0-31, 127, or 129-159 in their names (mostly unprintable / invisible). Empty folders can be added in SharePoint Designer using the New Folder button, but they're ignored during import operations.

Answer (score 5):

Just to pile on to the existing answers, this seems to be the most comprehensive answer [formatted for better readability]:

> You cannot use the following characters anywhere in a file name:
>
> - Tilde
> - Number sign
> - Percent
> - Ampersand
> - Asterisk
> - Braces
> - Backslash
> - Colon
> - Angle brackets
> - Question mark
> - Slash
> - Pipe
> - Quotation mark
>
> You cannot use the period character consecutively in the middle of a file name.
>
> You cannot use the period character at the end of a file name.
>
> You cannot start a file name by using the period character.
>
> If you use an underscore character (_) at the beginning of a file name, the file will be a hidden file.
>
> File names and folder names may not end with any of the following strings:
>
> - .files
> - _files
> - -Dateien
> - _fichiers
> - _bestanden
> - _file
> - _archivos
> - -filer
> - _tiedostot
> - _pliki
> - _soubory
> - _elemei
> - _ficheiros
> - _arquivos
> - _dosyalar
> - _datoteke
> - _fitxers
> - _failid
> - _fails
> - _bylos
> - _fajlovi
> - _fitxategiak
>
> In addition, file names and folder names cannot start with the “*vti*” string, such as the followings:
>
> - _vti_cnf
> - _vti_pvt
> - _vti_bin
> - _vti_txt

All of the above is from:

- [Information about the characters that you cannot use in site names, folder names, and file names in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/905231)

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joelo/archive/2007/06/27/file-name-length-size-and-invalid-character-restrictions-and-recommendations.aspx) is a list of restrictions in SharePoint. The characters it lists as not being able to be used in a folder name are ~ # % & * { } \ : < > ? / | 
"

Comment: +1 for a simple, yet complete answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's still true in SP2010 unfortunately - even though you can now upload, behind the scenes when you need to use functions such as
`System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(item_url)` and 
`SPEncode.UrlEncode(item_url)`, they will then unwantedly encode the forward slash as well as ignore ampersands, so it seems not worth the hassle. Same with SP2013 RTM too.

You can show any client/users it's not your fault currently by confirmation here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/905231 (covers up to SP2010).

Answer (score 1):

for checking, if a file name is valid in SharePoint, you also must prevent consecutive dots in the filename and a dot at the beginning or at the end of a filename.

Please see also here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/905231/en-us 
(there is also the plus sign "+" and a starting "_" mentioned as forbidden, but that works for SharePoint file names.

These are rquirements "on top" of being a valid Windows file name.
To check for a valid windows file name, you can use 
**Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()**

**c# code (without the dot checks)**

```
var invalidChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
var additionalInvalidSharePointSpecialCharacters = new char[7] { '~', '#', '%', '&', '{', '}', '+' };
invalidChars = invalidChars.Concat(additionalInvalidSharePointSpecialCharacters.AsEnumerable()).ToArray();

var failingDotsRemoved = Regex.Replace(new string(invalidCharsRemoved), @"\\.+", @".");

if (failingDotsRemoved[0].Equals('.'))
{
 failingDotsRemoved = failingDotsRemoved.Substring(1);
}

if (failingDotsRemoved[failingDotsRemoved.Length - 1].Equals('.'))
{
 failingDotsRemoved = failingDotsRemoved.Substring(0, failingDotsRemoved.Length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even easier, go to the site in question, go to the library, change the view to explorer view("View:" dropdown at top right of document view pane).

Then you can drag and drop the folder/subfolder/documents directly into sharepoint...maintains structure and will even allow empty folders

Comment: thanks!  i'm using forms based authentication! will it work. so far, fba has not been easy!

Comment: good question, we don't have any form based, but it will take you second to prove out whether it works, try it!

Comment: had to switch to windows! empty folders work but not folders with &!

thanks!

Comment: you can't get around the "&" issue, but you can at least retain your particular directory structure